# How to properly find the average of two angles?

Tags: average, angle

So basically, I’m making a game of golf in Python. This mostly just revolves around the math side of things, but if you really need to know, I’m using python Turtle.

This program is an advanced method of getting the angle at which to launch the ball. Simple enough. Originally, I had the user enter an angle from 1 to 360, which was functionally sound but just not intuitive for the user to play. So I decided on a new method for getting the angle from the user, which involved the WASD keys. The user would enter a string with these 4 characters, and depending how many of each character the user enters, the more the ball will head in that direction. For example, if I enter `“wwa”`, the ball will head North-NorthWest.

The problem I’m having is that if the user enters `“wd”`, the w and the d will average out to be 225 (which is the exact OPPOSITE of the desired result.) Is there any way to prevent this? The problem is obviously in the rounding, but I’m not sure where to start.
North = 360 , East = 90 , South = 180 and West = 270

No matter what you do, there will always be two values that are 270º apart from each other and cause this problem.

```
ballinput = input("Angle: ")
ballangle = 0
degreelist = [] #Each of the below statements appends the degrees
for i in range(ballinput.count("w")): #to the degree list
    degreelist.append(360) 
for i in range(ballinput.count("a")):
    degreelist.append(270)
for i in range(ballinput.count("s")):
    degreelist.append(180)
for i in range(ballinput.count("d")):
    degreelist.append(90)
for item in degreelist:
    ballangle += int(item) #which are added together so they can be
    ballangle /= len(ballinput) #averaged out into the final ball angle.
```

Comment: Shouldn't `w` be 0º? So the average of `wd` will be 45º ((0 + 90)/2)?

Comment: But then you realize that now `wa` is now 135. Thanks for pointing it out, though, I’ll add that to my question.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's purely a logic or mathematics question. Think carefully about *why* you get this result, and what causes it to happen; then think about *steps that the code needs to follow* in order to get the correct result regardless. Those steps would be the same in any programming language, and have nothing to do with how Python works.

Comment: Maybe it will be easier if you had `w=0` , `d=90`,  `a=-90` and `s` is either 180 or -180 depending on the context? In `as` context `s` would be -180, in `ds` context `s` is 180. `s = 180 if 'd' in my_string else -180`